# No eth0 on fresh Debian install

Tags: networking, debian, ethernet

I just installed Debian 9 on a Dell XPS 13. Since it has only USB-C ports, I use the Dell DA200 dongle for ethernet. But it seems like the ethernet port is no recognised because eth0 is not listed when I type `ip a`. I already added the following to `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I can't use apt-get update/upgrade/install because I have no internet connection. Is there anything I can do right now solve this?

Comment: Well, what interfaes _are_ listed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did the naming convention of network interfaces change in linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/914517/why-did-the-naming-convention-of-network-interfaces-change-in-linux)

Comment: @grawity there is 0: lo and 1: enxe...; So do I need to write enxe... in the interfaces file instead of eth0?